# Change hard disk but keep Windows 10 updated from 7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I have a notebook which used to have Windows 7 installed, then thanks to the free upgrade I updated it to Windows 10. Now, my Hard disk has broken and there are some sectors which are damaged, so I want to change it with a new one.

How can I install Windows 10 in the new hard disk and make it recognize my license key? I thought about cloning only the recovery partition to my new drive, but I'm not sure I can (since it's damaged) and also, I think it would re-install Windows 7.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Some info before we start.

You can indeed reinstall Windows 10 back onto the computer while using the windows 7 activation key. The reason behind this is Microsoft registers Windows 10 AND Windows 7 to that activation code. *Just in case you wanted to go back to Windows 7*

---

### The process

In order to reinstall Windows 10 back onto the laptop we will need to create an installation media *(most of the time a disk but can be a USB among other things)*. If we follow the steps found here: [create installation media](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10), in the second section titled "Using the tool to create installation media ..." we need to gather the following information:

1. Your Activation key ... *don't worry if you don't have this there is a tool to retrieve keys off of hard drives*
2. Your computers architecture ... *Usually represented as 32 or 64 bit*
3. You Windows 10 Version ... *Like Windows 10 Home or Pro*
4. The language ... *"English mother f#%$er, do you speak it!" - Pulp Fiction*

Please note that the last two will have carried over from the free Windows 10 upgrade. For example if you had Windows 7 Home Premium 32 Bit you will have upgraded to Windows 10 Home 32 Bit.

---

### The step by step guide

**What you will need:**

1. another computer to create the installation media
2. A flash drive that is at least 4GB in size **OR** a blank DVD and a DVD burner

**Let's begin**

On another computer with a stable internet connection, download the media creation tool from the page listed above or by clicking [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691209).

---

1. Once the program finishes downloading, run it. You will be prompted with a legal agreement. Please read through this and click accept *(only if you accept the agreement of course)*.
2. Once you click accept it will load stating "Getting a few things ready ...". When finished, you will have the option of "Upgrade this PC now" or "Create installation media for another PC", click "Create installation media for another PC" and click next.
3. You will now see a screen stating "Select language, architecture, and edition. **You must deselect the option saying "Use the recommended options for this PC**. Once deselected please change the Language, Edition, and Architecture accordingly. When finished please click next.
4. You will now have the option to store the installation to a USB or save it as an ISO file *(and ISO can be used to burn it to a DVD later)*. Select one accordingly and then click next.
   **NOTE: Any information on the USB will be erased after the creation of the installation media *(The same applies to a DVD if the DVD can be overwritten)*.**
5. Wait for the program to finish creating the installation media *(**this will take a while**)*. Once completed you will need to plug the media device into the laptop to start the process.
6. Reference this table below for the keyboard button that takes you to the "boot menu" by manufacturer.
   [image: List of boot menu keys by manufacturer]
   Turn on the laptop and repeatedly push the corresponding key for a list of devices you can boot from.
7. Select either the USB or the DVD drive in order to boot and install the media.
8. It will now load the installation and take you through the step by step process for installation.

---

### If you do not have the activation key

**PLEASE NOTE:** The Windows 10 activation key "signs" itself to your motherboard. You should not need the actual key for your Windows 10 to be activated, but it is good to have.
[Here is an article that talks about this.](http://www.howtogeek.com/244678/you-dont-need-a-product-key-to-install-and-use-windows-10/)

**If you wish to retrieve it**

You can retrieve the activation key by connecting the old hard drive into another computer *(like a workstation)* and installing and using the program [ProduKey](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html).

Here is what the program looks like:
[image: ProduKey]

Jot down the activation key *(I recommend writing all entries down for every item ... just in case)*

---

Comment: I wish you a good day.

Comment: Right back at ya